# Define KeyBindings in a UserControl, but have them applicable for the whole window?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts, inputbinding

There is a number of keyboard shortcuts that I'd like to be available application-wide, regardless of where the focus currently is.

At the moment I've got those defined as `<Window.InputBindings>` in my Main window's XAML.
All is good, but...
The Ribbon is encapsulated as a separate UserControl, and all the shortcuts are, naturally, related to the buttons that are in that Ribbon.
Consequently, I don't really like the smell of having 2 pieces of application logic dealing with the same functionality spread across the 2 classes.

Ideally, I would like to define the KeyBindings as `<Window.InputBindings>`, but in the UserControl, not in the window. Obviously, that cannot be done with XAML syntax, but only `<UserControl.InputBindings>` - alas, that would make them available only when the focus is on the Ribbon (which means *never*).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor of your control or in its Loaded() event handler, have it find the window in which it stands (use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) recursively until GetType is Window...), then add the InputBindings you want to that window.

Comment: Hi Vincent,
Thank you for this suggestion. I've been thinking along these lines myself... The only 2 objections (although not too significant) I have are:
1. Generally, I'm suspicious about climbing up the Visual Tree, as it breaks the control's encapsulation (since it needs to make certain assumptions on "the world outside"); in this particular case, though, it may be OK for a Ribbon to assume it will have a Window to reside in :-)
2. I'd prefer a declarative solution (i.e. in XAML) rather than programmatic (in code behind)... But, I guess, that's the best we can get :-)

Comment: Oh, and one more comment: this cannot be done in the control's constructor (since the main window is not fully constructed yet when the child controls' constructors are called).
So it has to be done at some later stage, e.g. in OnApplyTemplate.

Comment: ok :-) i was wondering also if it could be possible to declare the bindings at the application level, in the Application.xaml file.

Comment: I guess you can do that in app.xaml - in case you're following the default pattern, and have the initial view set there (because then you'll have the easy handle of the main window).
Yet, if you use some MVVM framework (like Galasoft), that may be less trivial...
What are you trying to achieve by that, anyway?

Comment: What i m trying to achieve : define once a key binding for the application (CTRL+S) for taking a 'smart' snapshot of the screen and put the result in a given directory with TimeStamp in the file name. Not a priority those days, though, i ll take a look on it in a few weeks.

Comment: Won't defining it in the main window's XAML (as in <Window.InputBindings>) be sufficient?